# openldap : ldapsearch ldap_bind: Invalid credentils (46)

Tags: docker, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to ldapsearch from host to a container but it's not working.

I start with :

```
docker run --env LDAP_ORGANISATION="OpenLdap" --env LDAP_DOMAIN="example.org" --env LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD="admin" -p 389:389 -p 636:636 --name openldap --detach osixia/openldap:1.5.0
```

Then this works :

```
$ docker exec openldap ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w admin
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# example.org
dn: dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: OpenLdap
dc: example

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

but this doesn't when executed directly from the host :

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w admin
```

Result :

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Your `docker run` looks suspect. If you run that actual command without the `--detach` option, you  should see an error message like `run: error: unrecognized arguments: --env --env LDAP_DOMAIN=example.org --env LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin`. All those `--env` options need to come *before* the image name (they are arguments to `docker run`, not to the image).

Comment: My bad, I fixed the question (thank you for editing the question by the way!).
I still get the same error : ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Comment: The ldapsearch works when I'm inside the container (docker exec) but not when I'm outside. I thought it would be a hostname probleme but I tried many things on that. Maybe it's not taking the -w option for the password ?

Comment: With the corrected `docker run` command line, this all works fine for me -- I can run `ldapsearch` successfully both inside and outside the container. Are you certain nothing else is listening on port 389 on your system? With the container stopped, what does `ss -tln | grep 389` show? (Or `netstat` if you don't have `ss`)

Comment: that was exactly it. I had 2 tasks running on port 389 when i launched : 
netstat -ano | findstr :389 
-- I stopped them both by stopping all containers and killing the remaining process on windows with this command : taskkill /PID <PID> /F
-- Can you put you answer on the main thread so i can accept it as the correct answer please ? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this on my local system, and with the corrected `docker run` command line...

```
docker run \
  --env LDAP_ORGANISATION="OpenLdap" \
  --env LDAP_DOMAIN="example.org" \
  --env LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD="admin" \
  -p 389:389 \
  -p 636:636 \
  --name openldap \
  --detach osixia/openldap:1.5.0
```

...I can successfully run your `ldapsearch` commands both inside and
outside the container. The behavior you're seeing suggests that when
you're running `ldapsearch` on the host, it's not connecting to the
same ldap server that you're using inside the container.

You need to check to see if anything else is listening on port 389 on
your system. Under Linux, you can do this by running `netstat -tln`;
if you're on Windows, the equivalent command is `netstat -aon`.

If you find something else listening on port 389, your options are (a)
kill it or (b) map the containerized service to a different port.